# Testing out simple features for a game, cannot get an object to jump

Tags: java, game-physics

I am trying to get a ball to bounce up and down when you press the up arrow key. I can get the ball to move up but it will not stop moving up. I have written the code for the ball movement in my update method. I am trying to get the ball to stop at y coordinate 400, but it just passes it up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

int x,y;
public static int width = 300;
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
public static int scale = 3;
private boolean running = false;

public Thread thread;
public JFrame frame;
public Keyboard key;

private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    frame = new JFrame();
    key = new Keyboard();
    addKeyListener(key);
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double nanoSeconds = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int gameUpdates = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    requestFocus();

    while(running){

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nanoSeconds;
        lastTime = now;
        //this ensures that delta only updates the screen 60 times each second
        while (delta >= 1){
            update();
            gameUpdates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        //this if statement happens once a second
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            frame.setTitle("Bouncy Ball!  ~ ~ ~  Updates per second: " + gameUpdates + ". Frames per second: " + frames + ".");
            gameUpdates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}

int yy;

public void update() {
    key.update();

    y = y + yy;

   if(key.up){
       yy = -5;
       if(y == 400){
           yy = 0;}

   }
}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.fillOval(300,y+435,50,50);


    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game game = new Game();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setTitle("Bouncy Ball");

    game.start();
}
}
```

This is my keylisener class

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Keyboard implements KeyListener{

private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];
public boolean up, down, left, right;

public void update(){

    up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP];
    down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN];
    left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT];
    right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT];

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

}
```

Comment: IF you want the ball to bounce as you say, you'll need to add gravity to your computation for object position.

Comment: I will implement gravity, but first I need to worry about more basic things like getting my ball to stop. I can't even do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the key.update() method. key.up will only be true *while* you're holding the up key, not just if you press the up key once. If, for now, you only care about a single button press, change it to:

```
public void update() {
    if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP]) {
        up = true;
    }
}
```

Which will only update once, once you press up, and keys.up will stay true.

Also, y is decreasing, not increasing (you're subtracting 5 from it), so you want to change 
`== 400` to `== 400`, or even better, `<= 400`, in case you don't increment with whole numbers (as per the other answer).

As a general debugging idea: At that if statement, I printed out the value of y, and noticed it only printed out 3 or 4 values (corresponding to how long I was holding it down), which meant that the if statement wasn't being checked, or wasn't returning true (which was the case here).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
   if(key.up){
   yy = -5;
   if(y == 400){
       yy = 0;}
```

}

try:

```
   if(key.up){
   yy = -5;
   if(y >= 400){
       yy = 0;}
```

}

If your ball is moving at 5px per update then it may pass 400px without actually
equaling 400px, this is why you check if it is greater than 400px.

Comment: I tried your code but the ball still went straight up!

Comment: @krzysztof, interesting. I'm assuming your using a sprite for the ball? Maybe your sprite is not using the same y as you are editing.